# OpenCV PointCloud from Depth map

Tags: c++, opencv, 3d, stereo-3d

I am trying to generate a point cloud with my Minoru3D stereo camera, but it does not work. 
The generated points are definitely not correct. 
The camera is correctly calibrated. 
My rectified images(rec1, rec2), the disparity map(disp) and the depth map(depth):

[image]

And the pointcloud: 
[image]

I create the depth image with reprojectImageTo3D and then read the points at every pixel. 
Full Code:

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/contrib/contrib.hpp>
#include <opencv2/calib3d/calib3d.hpp>
#include "libcam.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fstream>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    // The camera properties
    int w = 640;
    int h = 480;
    int fps = 20;

    // The images, which are proceeded
    Mat img1, img2;
    // The grayscale versions of the images
    Mat gray1, gray2;
    // The disparity and depth map
    Mat disparity;
    Mat depth(Size(h, w), CV_32FC3);
    // The iplImage versions of the images used to get the images from the camera
    IplImage *iplImg1 = cvCreateImage(cvSize(w, h), 8, 3), *iplImg2 = cvCreateImage(cvSize(w, h), 8, 3);

    // The cameras
    Camera cam1("/dev/video0", w, h, fps), cam2("/dev/video1", w, h, fps);

    // Load the camera model
    Mat CM1, CM2, D1, D2, R, T, E, F, R1, R2, P1, P2, Q;
    FileStorage fs("data/stereocalib.yml", FileStorage::READ);
    fs["CM1"] >> CM1;
    fs["CM2"] >> CM2;
    fs["D1"] >> D1;
    fs["D2"] >> D2;
    fs["R"] >> R;
    fs["T"] >> T;
    fs["E"] >> E;
    fs["F"] >> F;
    fs["R1"] >> R1;
    fs["R2"] >> R2;
    fs["P1"] >> P1;
    fs["P2"] >> P2;
    fs["Q"] >> Q;
    fs.release();

    Mat map1x = Mat(h, w, CV_32F);
    Mat map1y = Mat(h, w, CV_32F);
    Mat map2x = Mat(h, w, CV_32F);
    Mat map2y = Mat(h, w, CV_32F);
    initUndistortRectifyMap(CM1, D1, R1, P1, cvSize(w, h), CV_32FC1, map1x, map1y);
    initUndistortRectifyMap(CM2, D2, R2, P2, cvSize(w, h), CV_32FC1, map2x, map2y);

    // The rectified images
    Mat imgU1 = Mat(img1.size(), img1.type()), imgU2 = Mat(img2.size(), img2.type());

    Ptr<StereoBM> sbm = createStereoBM(16 * 10, 5);

    while (true) {

        // Get the images from the cameras
        cam1.Update();
        cam2.Update();
        cam1.toIplImage(iplImg1);
        cam2.toIplImage(iplImg2);
        img1 = cvarrToMat(iplImg1);
        img2 = cvarrToMat(iplImg2);

        // Rectify
        remap(img1, imgU1, map1x, map1y, INTER_LINEAR, BORDER_CONSTANT, Scalar());
        remap(img2, imgU2, map2x, map2y, INTER_LINEAR, BORDER_CONSTANT, Scalar());

        // Convert the rectified images to grayscale images
        cvtColor(imgU1, gray1, CV_BGR2GRAY);
        cvtColor(imgU2, gray2, CV_BGR2GRAY);

        // Create disparity map
        sbm->compute(gray1, gray2, disparity);

        // Create depth map
        reprojectImageTo3D(disparity, depth, Q, true, CV_32F);

        //imshow("img1", img1);
        //imshow("img2", img2);
        imshow("rec1", gray1);
        imshow("rec2", gray2);
        imshow("disp", disparity);
        imshow("depth", depth);

        int key = waitKey(10);
        if (key == 'q') {
            break;
        }
        else if (key == 's') {

            stringstream output;
            for (int x = 0; x < img1.rows; x++) {
                for (int y = 0; y < img1.cols; y++) {
                    Point3f p = depth.at<Point3f>(x, y);
                    if(p.z >= 10000) continue;  // Filter errors
                    output << p.x << "," << p.y << "," << p.z << endl;
                }
            }

            ofstream outputFile("points");
            outputFile << output.str();
            outputFile.close();

            cout << "saved" << endl;
        }
        else if (key == 'p') {
            waitKey(0);
        }
    }
    destroyAllWindows();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: looking at the final image (depth) i would definitely say you have a matrix precision bug (16 or 32F)

Comment: Given your disparity image is correct (which I am not able to judge from the picture) there may be a bug in reprojectImageTo3D. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22418846/reprojectimageto3d-in-opencv

Comment: The Types are: 
gray1: CV_8UC1; 
gray2: CV_8UC1; 
disp: CV_16SC1; 
depth: CV_32FC3; 
Q: CV_64FC1; 
@canberk When I try to convert disparity to CV_32FC1 it does not work. I am using `disparity.convertTo(disparity, CV_32F, 1.0/16);`. The disparity image then is black and white only. Maybe there is some other way to convert it?

Comment: @Kozuch I tried the code from the other question you mentioned. For using the code without errors I had to convert Q from CV_65FC1 to CV_32FC1 using `Q.convertTo(Q, 32FC1);`. But it does not work

Comment: Did you solve  your problem yet ?

Comment: Yes, check https://github.com/viz3d/viz3d/blob/master/viz3d/point_cloud.py

I think the problem in the questions code were some image format issues