# Point cloud from reprojectImageTo3D looks like a cone

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm trying to generate a point cloud from the images captured by two cameras.

The calibration was done using the sample calibration code that ships with OpenCV and it seems to work. The image below shows a pair of rectified images and the lines pass through corresponding regions of the images as they are supposed to. The calibration program also reports a RMS error of 0.398208 and an average epipolar error of 0.379794.

[image: Calibration results]

The disparity computation also seems to work. As shown on the image below, the disparity map is what I expect it to be.

[image: Disparity map]

Then, I use `reprojectImageTo3D` to generate the 3D points. It receives as parameters the disparity map (converted to floating point by `disparity16.convertTo(disparity,CV_32F,1/16.0);`) and the `Q` matrix obtained through calibration. In my case, the matrix is:

```
 [ 1., 0., 0.                    , -3.5430333328247070e+02,
   0., 1., 0.                    , -2.3768853569030762e+02,
   0., 0., 0.                    , 6.5857641483241434e+02 ,
   0., 0., 7.7531807099024491e-02, 0.                      ]
```

But, when I export that data to a `.ply` file and open it on MeshLab, I get this weird cone-shaped object:

[image: MeshLab visualization]

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22418846/reprojectimageto3d-in-opencv) question seems to be about the same problem and the accepted answer suggests replacing `reprojectImageTo3D` with custom code. I tried it and some other random pieces of code I found online, but I always end up with this cone-shaped thing.

I suspect there's something wrong with my calibration. I'm using a quite weird camera setup. I have two Raspberry Pis, each one connected to a Raspberry Pi Camera and the images are transfered over Wi-Fi to the computer that processes them. I know that ideally the left and right images should be captured exactly at the same time and that in my setup that is definitely not happening. I don't have a precise measurement of the time difference between the captures and I don't know how much it can interfere on the final result, but before changing my setup, I'd like to know if someone has had a similar problem and if there is a solution for it.

**Adding more information as requested:**
I'm using the Semi-Global Block Matcher (StereoSGBM), with parameters:

```
minDisparity: 0
numDisparities: 128
SADWindowSize: 5
P1: 600
P2: 2400
disp12MaxDiff: 10
preFilterCap: 4
uniquenessRatio: 1
speckleWindowSize: 150
speckleRange: 2
```

And here are the left and right rectified images and the corresponding disparity. Disparity was converted to `CV_8U` for display by `normalize(disparity,disp,0,255,CV_MINMAX,CV_8U)`, but during the computation of the point cloud I use the `CV_32F` values, as mentioned above.
[image: Left camera image]
[image: Right camera image]
[image: Disparity map]

Comment: It would be better if you share your input Rectified images & the algorithm you used & its parameters

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I added the requested information to the question.